# how can i find the avg of a column in in days of the week CVS using panda

Tags: python, excel, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to find the avg of orders in days of the week from csv file
[image: an example of the excel file]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/samer/Desktop/project/online_retail2.xlsx")

df['invoicedate']=pd.to_datetime(df['invoicedate'])
date = df["invoicedate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["invoicedate"]).dt.dayofweek
df["invoicedate"].mean()
```

The answer I got was 3, but for how long the list is and i don't think this is the avg of days of the week, any help?

example of the answer [image]

Comment: If you could give the link to the csv file it would be easier to find the issue.

Comment: i don't know how to send it as a file im sry

Comment: A google sheet link will do tbh.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D28xzlpjDyYaG2SjQH1ET45Ocr5md3yX/edit#gid=1748797990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have calculated is that the average weekday of your invoices is "3", i.e. Thursday. That does sound reasonable.

If you want to calculate the average of a metric on all the weekdays separately (e.g. average invoice amount on Monday, Tuesday,...), you have to use groupby like [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html), but I am not entirely sure that this is what you want, based on your description. Maybe you can clarify with an example of your desired output?

Edit:
If you want avg orders for weekdays try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./groupby_example.xlsx')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['weekday'] = df['date'].dt.dayofweek
df.groupby('weekday').mean()
```

Comment: The best way i can describe it, is that i want all the week days in cvs averaged into one number, so i can print it

Comment: well, I hope this does the trick for you:

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("./groupby_example.xlsx")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df["weekday"] = df['date'].dt.dayofweek
df.groupby('weekday').mean()
```
I'll put that in my original answer again, formatting does not like me, sorry.

Comment: just a small question if i want to make the answer as int not a float, should i just add int to the last code?

Comment: adding `.astype('int32')` should do the trick